# Why useFirebirdAutocommit=true won't work and additionally disable JDBC autocommit

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, autocommit, jaybird

I use to connect with Firebird:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
```

But if I set:

```
ds.addConnectionProperty("autoCommit", "true");
ds.addConnectionProperty(FBConnectionProperties.USE_FIREBIRD_AUTOCOMMIT, "true");
```

or

```
ds.addConnectionProperty("useFirebirdAutocommit", "true");
```

Autocommit won't work at all. It only works, if I will not use `"useFirebirdAutocommit"` property.

Or if I add **isc_tpb_autocommit** it also works:

```
ds.addConnectionProperty("TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED", "isc_tpb_read_committed,"+
                "isc_tpb_rec_version,isc_tpb_write,isc_tpb_wait,**isc_tpb_autocommit**");
```

It seems that use of internal server auto-commit, disable autocommiting by driver, but internal server auto-commit not work.

By the way - in result of that, I was sure that I have autocommit - but each update make another version of record with not committed transaction that could not be sweeped. Database file grow very fast from 3MB to 15GB in few days 24/7 (about 1000 updates per second).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and describe the exact problem you're having. And also, as described in the documentation, the `useFirebirdAutoCommit` option is experimental (and will probably always remain so). It has some severe downsides, including pinning the transaction, which will indeed hinder garbage collection.

Comment: Also please explain how the _"autocommit doesn't work"_ (as in: is data not visible to other transactions?). If the actual problem is the growth of your database, then that is exactly **because** you're using `useFirebirdAutocommit` with long running connections. Using `useFirebirdAutoCommit` will not actually commit the transaction handle, and due to its internal mechanisms, this means garbage collection is inhibited, which will be especially painful for long-living connections that are continuously in auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I'm assuming the growth of record versions and file size are the only problems you're experiencing. If that is not the case, then please update your question and provide more details of the problem.

As described in the [documentation](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#ref-firebirdautocommit), when you enable the `useFirebirdAutocommit` option, then:

> Jaybird itself will not commit until connection close (or switching to
> `autoCommit=false`).

In other words, the fact that the driver does not commit in auto-commit, when `useFirebirdAutocommit` is enabled, is intended behaviour of this feature (in fact, it is its whole raison d'être). Instead, the server will internally perform a `commit retain` after each executed statement, while preserving the transaction handle. This will make the changes visible to other transactions, while avoiding the overhead of extra network round-trips.

However, the use of `commit retain` has downsides: because it retains the original transaction handle, it will pin the original transaction and the transactions it is interested in, causing garbage collection to be inhibited until the transaction handle is actually committed. In addition, when using a transaction isolation level other than read committed, it will not change the visible record set.

So, if you use this with long-running connections that never use actual transactions (i.e. you never disable auto-commit), you will inhibit garbage collection for a very long time. If you have a lot of updates, this can indeed lead to extreme growth of record versions and the database file itself.

This is the primary reason this feature is marked experimental, and why the documentation says:

> Support for this option is experimental, and should only be enabled if
> you 1) know what you’re doing, and 2) really need this feature.
> Internally `isc_tpb_autocommit` uses `commit_retaining`, which means
> that using this feature may increase the transaction gap with
> associated sweep and garbage collection impact.

Unless you use short-living connections, or otherwise switch between auto-commit enabled and disabled regularly, then the `useFirebirdAutocommit` mode is not something you should be using.

If you do insist on using this feature, then make sure that your connections are short-lived (e.g. reduce the maximum connection lifetime, DBCP property `maxConnLifetimeMillis`), or that you regularly force a real commit by disabling (and enabling) auto-commit.

These downsides are the reason this feature is experimental, and will likely always remain so.

As to why redefining `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` does (seem to) work, is because - assuming `useFirebirdAutocommit` is not enabled - the auto-commit transaction will still be really committed by the driver after each statement completion. Manually adding `isc_tpb_autocommit` to a transaction definition when you only ever use auto-commit has little to no benefit (in fact, it has slightly more overhead because of the internal `commit retain` and the actual commit).

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Jaybird